# Random.Next is not giving a random number

Tags: c#, random

Hi
This how I used the random but it always gives "1" index to indexOfAChosenListCell.
When I debug it it shows different values, but on regular running I get the same move every time..
What is the problem with Random , it's static not random... :)

```
internal Square getAutomaticMove()                      
{
            List<Square> LegalMovesArray = GetLegalSquares();
            Random randomListCell = new Random();
            int indexOfAChosenListCell = 0;

            if (CheckForLegalSquares())    
            {
                 indexOfAChosenListCell = randomListCell.Next(LegalMovesArray.Count-1);
            }
```

Comment: Hint: what is the value of LegalMovesArray.Count-1 ?  Also, move the construction of your Random outside getAutomaticMove()

Comment: @Mitch: thanks for your answer , but what is the problem with LegalMovesArray.Count-1, I want to toss an index in the LegalMovesArray and it doesn't have an index whi ch is equal to LegalMovesArray.Count...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest seeding the random numer generator too.  As I understand, you will end up with the same psuedo-random number sequence every time you run the application.  I may be mistaken.

```
int Seed = (int)DateTime.Now.Ticks;
Random randomListCell = new Random(Seed);
```

Comment: this doesn't make a difference *at all* - this is what the default constructor `new Random()` does internally anyway. The key is to initialize `randomListCell` only once and then call `Next()` on this instance.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: I agree, that he should create an instance variable, and that your answer is correct.  I was unaware that the default constructor did this automatically.  In my experience I've had to seed.  Isn't that why there is a constructor that takes a seed?  I was only adding to the conversation.

Comment: `Random` creates a sequence of pseudo-random numbers - this sequence is always the same for the same seed - so you usually pass a seed if you want to *reproduce* a sequence that you used before.

Comment: @Anx+@Mulder: Please read: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx. It writes about the default constructor (the one you use in your question): "Initializes a new instance of the Random class, using a time-dependent default seed value.". So the `new Random()` does the same as `new Random(seed)`. Please explain how this is a different answer? Please tell ur how this answer could have been accepted as correct?

Comment: Even with this approach, if you try to create several random numbers in succession, you will still get the same number.

Answer (score 21):

make `randomListCell` an instance variable and only initialize it *once* - otherwise you will keep getting the same numbers again.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx):

> By default, the parameterless
>   constructor of the Random class uses
>   the system clock to generate its seed
>   value, while its parameterized
>   constructor can take an Int32 value
>   based on the number of ticks in the
>   current time.
>   **However, because the clock has finite resolution, using the parameterless constructor to create** 
>   **different Random objects in close succession creates random number**
>    **generators that produce identical**
>    **sequences of random numbers.**

Answer (score 5):

[`Random.Next(Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5.aspx)

> Returns a nonnegative random number **less than** the specified maximum

So the largest number you'll ever get is `Count - 2`, probably not what you wanted.

Comment: I want a number from 0 to size of array-1 which means last cell

Comment: @Mulder: Then you need to call `randomListCell.Next(array.Length)`, because the RNG will already exclude the value you pass it, no need to subtract 1.

Answer (score 4):

Declare Random as a private member variable, then instantiate it the constructor, and only call Random.Next in your method.

Answer (score 3):

Your random should be create outside the function

```
Random randomListCell = new Random();

internal Square getAutomaticMove()                      
{
            List<Square> LegalMovesArray = GetLegalSquares();
            int indexOfAChosenListCell = 0;

            if (CheckForLegalSquares())    
            {
                 indexOfAChosenListCell = randomListCell.Next(LegalMovesArray.Count-1);
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't create a new Random every time you need a new number; if you want a sequence of different random numbers, you want to keep a single Random object and ask it repeatedly for new ones.

Answer (score 2):

I'll show the difference:

```
var random = new Random();
var color = Color.FromArgb(200, random.Next(255), // 222
                                random.Next(255), // 33
                                random.Next(255)); // 147
```

Result: #DE2193

```
var color = Color.FromArgb(200, new Random().Next(255), // 153
                                new Random().Next(255), // 153
                                new Random().Next(255)); // 153
```

Result: #999999

Answer (score 0):

declare Random object outside the function, so that it use same object to generate new number. You are creating new object every time which use same seed and gives you mostly same numbers...

```
static Random randomListCell = new Random();
internal Square getAutomaticMove()                      
{
            List<Square> LegalMovesArray = GetLegalSquares();

            int indexOfAChosenListCell = 0;

            if (CheckForLegalSquares())    
            {
                 indexOfAChosenListCell = randomListCell.Next(LegalMovesArray.Count-1);
            }
}
```